# Python: connect 4 play

Tags: python

Hi i am new to python and i am creating a connect 4 game, i am on the final bit, the play function which allows the game to be played. The issue appears to be my while loop, it runs once, ask the user for a column and inputs the counter in that column, however after that it just keeps on asking which column to select and not changing the board:

```
who = game['who']
    while who != 'computer':
        x = int(input("Which column to select? "))
        game['board'] = board2
        l = getValidMoves(game['board'])
        if x in l:
            game['board'] = makeMove(board2, x, who)
            printBoard(game['board'])            
            board = game['board']
            if hasWon(game['board'], who) == True:                        
                print("{who} has won.")
                sys.exit()
```

You can see when i run this code i get:

```
Which column to select? 1
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
---------------
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | |
| |X| | | | | |

Which column to select? 2

Which column to select?
```

I think the issue is that the while loop is stopping running after asking for what column to select. Any help would be appreciated.

My printBoard function is:

```
print("|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|")
    print("---------------")        
    for j in range(6):
        for i in range(7):
            if board[j][i] == 1:
                board[j][i] = "X"
            elif board[j][i] == 2:
                board[j][i] = "O"
            elif board[j][i] == 0:
                board[j][i] = " "                           
    for j in range(6):
        print("|"+"|".join(str(board[j][i]) for i in range(7))+"|")   
    return None
```

My getValidMoves is:

```
l = list()
for i in range(7):
    if board[0][i] == 0:
        l.append(i)   
return l
enter code here
```

and my makeMove is:

```
if who == 1:
    for i in [5,4,3,2,1,0]:
        if board[i][move] == 0:
            break
    board[i][move] = 1

elif who == 2:
    for i in [5,4,3,2,1,0]:
        if board[i][move] ==  0:
            break
    board[i][move] = 2              
return board
```

Comment: What does your methods return or what is `board2`? Have you tried printing the return values? Especially `getValidMoves()`.

Comment: You need to provide more information like your `getValidMoves`, `makeMove` and `printBoard` functions are running correctly or not. A line-by-line debugger can help you figure out where you are going wrong. You can also try adding `print` statements so you know till what point things are going as intended.

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with functions such as `getValidMoves`, `makeMove` etc?

Comment: your while loop doesn't seam to stop because it continues to ask for input. I would assume the problem is either in updating the board or in printing the updated board, which is why the other comments are exactly right to ask for clarification on these methods

Comment: Please check how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently we can not reproduce your problem. (e.g. `game`, `board2` not define)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop continues as long as `who` does not equal "computer". But nothing inside the loop ever changes `who`, so it will *never* equal "computer" and the loop will never complete.

Comment: ah right, so could i add something such as, if who == 1: who2 = 2    elif who == 2: who2 = 1?